# Duplicate code is not detected

Tags: c#, sonarqube, continuous-integration, azure-devops, pull-request

I'm using Sonarqube with VSTS. But for some reason duplicate code is only reported (i.e. the message is added to PR) if two methods are identical. But let's say those methods are almost identical:

```
public void A(int a) {
    if(a == 0)
        return;
    // code from B
}

public void B(int a) {
    // some code
}
```

then it is not reported.
Is it possible to make SonarQube add comments for this type of code duplicates?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it is possible or not, but here are two reasons why it might be a bad idea:

1. There's no obvious cutoff for how small a piece of "duplicate" code
   can be. If the same three lines of code show up in many different
   places, do you really want to flag that?
2. Related to the first: finding duplicated code without an "anchor" such as an enclosing block is insanely computationally expensive, especially if the section can be any length. The duplicate check would have to start on every line and examine "chunks" of many sizes to see if they're repeated elsewhere. This is orders of magnitude more work than what it is doing currently.

Comment: AFAIK, by default SonarQube requires at least 10 LoC to mark the block as a duplicate.

Comment: And if I go into SonarQube portal it will show duplicates including the one above. But it won't report them in a PR.

Comment: @artur Ah, I see. In that case I wouldn't know what to try. Sorry I can't help.